How to correctly convert from DateTime to DateOnly and compare values in .Net 8.0 with c#?
Explanation
I am trying to compare some database table data with the date of today and then show them in order by Id.
I managed to found way to convert the datetime of today into dateonly, but on page load i get an error:

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)

From the debugger the error seems to be:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateOnly' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Question
What is wrong with this code, what is the correct way of converting DateTime into DateOnly?
The code:
@foreach (var item in Model.PL.Where(p => p.PidDate == DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(i))).OrderBy(p => p.Id))  
{}

where PidDate in the table is defined as:
public DateOnly PidDate { get; set; }

The full error as shown in the browser:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing 

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
       
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)  
System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)

        TESTNET8.Pages.Pro.Pages_Pro_Historiku+<>c__DisplayClass206_0+<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in Historiku.cshtml

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()  
TESTNET8.Pages.Pro.Pages_Pro_Historiku.ExecuteAsync() in Historiku.cshtml   
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|22_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Program+<>c+<<<Main>$>b__0_10>d.MoveNext() in Program.cs

await next(); 

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)



You can first check if the model is empty in your method, If the model in the method has no data:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ViewModel
    {
    
       
    
    };

    return View(model);
}

View:
@model ViewModel


@foreach (var item in Model.PL.Where(p => p.piddate == DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1))).OrderBy(p => p.Id))
{
    <div>
        
        <p>PidDate: @item.Id</p>
        <p>PidDate: @item.piddate</p>
    </div>
}
<div id="result"></div>


After I added the relevant data examples:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ViewModel
    {
        PL = new List<PidDate>
    {
        new PidDate { Id = 1, piddate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-2)) },
        new PidDate { Id = 2, piddate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)) },
        new PidDate { Id = 3, piddate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow) },
        new PidDate { Id = 4, piddate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)) },
        new PidDate { Id = 5, piddate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2)) },

    
    }
    };

    return View(model);
}

Types can be converted normally.

Regarding the IConvertible interface, this interface provides methods to convert the value of an instance of the implementation type to a common language runtime type with an equivalent value. Common language runtime types include Boolean, SByte, Byte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, Single, Double, Decimal, DateTime, Char, and String. If there is no meaningful conversion of the common language runtime type, an InvalidCastException will be thrown. For details, you can refer to this document .and check whether there is a method in your method that uses the IConvertible interface to convert DateOnly objects.For how to use datetime to convert to dateonly type, you can refer to this document.

the data is dynamically red directly from the database (in .net 7.0 it works just fine). The table is correctly called in the model as you have shown too. On the table, Not all days have values. This is what baffles me. I am reading all the documentation you provided.

Both DateTime and DateOnly are structs, so they can't be the source of NREs. The only two possibilities in that line of code are:

Model
Model.PL

Use a debugger and find what you're passing as null.

I get this:  System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateOnly' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

Make up your mind, is it NRE or invalid cast? Your stack trace clearly shows NRE, so why are you claiming invalid cast now? Can you just post a fully compilable, minimal project that shows the problem?

Sorry but this is what the debugger showed up. I just uploaded the error showed in the browser and then the error shown in the debugger.
